# User Input of int won't be null

Tags: android, validation, android-studio, input

I made a code where user put value between some range and my code generate random number for them. Randomization working properly but when fields are blank my app is crash how should I fix it.

randNum.java

```
Button generateNum = findViewById(R.id.generate_number);

generateNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText et = findViewById(R.id.fromNum);
        String sTextFromET = et.getText().toString();
        int fNum = Integer.valueOf(sTextFromET);


        EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.toNum);
        String sTextFromET1 = et1.getText().toString();
        int sNum = Integer.valueOf(sTextFromET1);

        TextView ans = findViewById(R.id.ans);

        //                if(sNum == null || fNum == null){
            //
            //                    ans.setText(getString(R.string.enterNumError));
            //
            //                }
        //                else
        if(sNum < fNum){

            ans.setText(getString(R.string.max_min_error));

        }else {

            final int random = new Random().nextInt((sNum - fNum) + 1) + fNum;
            String ras = Integer.toString(random);
            ans.setText(ras);

        }

    }
});
```

I try to use `null` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle **NumberFormatException** thrown by **Integer.valueOf()** function

```
try {
      EditText et = findViewById(R.id.fromNum);
      String sTextFromET = et.getText().toString();
      int fNum = Integer.valueOf(sTextFromET);


      EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.toNum);
      String sTextFromET1 = et1.getText().toString();
      int sNum = Integer.valueOf(sTextFromET1);

      TextView ans = findViewById(R.id.ans);

      if(sNum < fNum){
          ans.setText(getString(R.string.max_min_error));
      }else {
          final int random = new Random().nextInt((sNum - fNum) + 1) + fNum;
          String ras = Integer.toString(random);
          ans.setText(ras);
      }
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put validation first on button click. (For checking if user has entered nothing or just spaces in any of edittexts).

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            strNum1 = edtl.getText().toString().trim();
            strNum2 = edt2.getText().toString().trim();

            if (strNum1.length() == 0)
            {
                showAlert("Please enter Num 1");
            }
            else if (strNum2.length() == 0)
            {
                showAlert("Please enter Num 2");
            }
            else
            {
                int numvalue1 = Integer.parseInt(strNum1);
                int numvalue2 = Integer.parseInt(strNum2);
                generateNum (numvalue1, numvalue2);  //Call your function for generation of random number here
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps you understand the validation of forms for empty input fields.

P.S: I would recommend you put inputType attribute for your EditTexts if you have not added it already in xml file like:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

So you can avoid exception at `Integer.parseInt` if user enters any alphabet or symbol.

Comment: I have already add android:inputType="number", I change my code as per you suggest now .lenghth() is not resolving error occurred

Comment: Update your question with new code, so I can have a look at it.

Comment: IMO `TextUtils.isEmpty(strNum1)` is far better than `.length()` method to handle this type of situation. And yes, using `android:inputType="number"` is a good idea as it prevents user from entering non-numeric values in text inputs.